# Owncloud problem: localhost/owncloud offers phtml file to download instead of showing a website

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, owncloud-server

I have installed owncloud, apache2, php and all the other stuff on a fresh Ubuntu system (14.04) (owncloud version 8).
The apache server works, but if I want to connect to localhost/owncloud it just shows me the message, that I can download a phtml file, it doesn't show me a site.

Has someone an idea what I did wrong or what could help?

Comment: Hi Felix and welcome on AskUbuntu.com! :-D You will not find German advice here as this is (you correctly noticed) an only English-speaking forum, although there are some Germans around (like me...). But there is no need to apologize for your language - it is good and much better than what we sometimes find here! With your question, I can't help you, unfortunately, because I am not very well informed about this kind of networking. You will find somebody else...

Comment: Anyway, thxs :)

Comment: How did you set it up? Can you post at least the Apache configuration for Owncloud?